# change the value of the src attribute of all the image

Tags: javascript, html

in html i am changing `img` tag `src` with javascript. but it only change the first one i need to change all the `img` `src` . How can i change it?

**html**

```
<img src="compman01.gif" width="107" height="98">
<img src="compman02.gif" width="107" height="98">
<img src="compman03.gif" width="107" height="98">
<img src="compman04.gif" width="107" height="98">
<img src="compman05.gif" width="107" height="98">
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "hackanm.gif";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
  img.setAttribute('src', "hackanm.gif");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("img")` will return an array like object which you can loop through.

```
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = "hackanm.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").forEach((imgElement) =>{
  imgElement.src = "hackanm.gif";
  
});
```